# WPF TargetNullValue Source From Code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, targetnullvalue

In my code I have a string:

```
Dim a As String
a = "This string is dynamic"
```

In my XAML want to set the `TargetNullValue` of my `DataGridTextColumn` equal to a.

I know I can set `TargetNullValue=This string is dynamic`, but, as implied, a is dynamic.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565213/how-to-bind-a-localized-string-in-the-targetnullvalue-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to make an `IValueConverter` and do something like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding variableName, Converter={StaticResource NullConverter}" />
```

If the object passed to your converter is `null`, you can do your return your dynamic string.

Comment: Ah I was afraid of that haha. Thank you!

Comment: @Turkwise Yeah, some things require a little more work than you'd think. Good luck!