# WPF: Change DataContext if Null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a view that I would like to assign a "backup" viewmodel to. Essentially if "Generic" is null I would like to set the DataContext to "GenericFactory". "GenericFactory" is able to create an instance of the "Generic" viewmodel. Upon creation the viewmodel is assigned to the appropriate property and the PropertyChanged event is fired, however given the code below the only DataContext I'm ever bound to is "GenericFactory". Can anyone explain and/or offer an alternative solution?

XAML

```
<Page x:Class="GenericProject.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:GenericProject.View">
    <StackPanel>
        <!--Additional markup-->
        <vw:GenericView>
            <vw:GenericView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type vw:GenericView}">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Generic}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Generic}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding GenericFactory}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </vw:GenericView.Style>
        </vw:GenericView>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public GenericViewModel Generic
    {
        get { return _generic; }
        private set
        {
            if (_generic != value)
            {
                _generic = value;
                base.OnPropertyChanged("Generic");
            } 
        }
    }

    public GenericFactoryViewModel GenericFactory { get; private set; }

    private void OnGenericFactoryCreatedGeneric(object sender, CreatedGenericEventArgs e)
    {
        Generic = e.Generic;
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        GenericFactory = new GenericFactoryViewModel();
        GenericFactory.CreatedGeneric += OnGenericFactoryCreatedGeneric;
    }
}
```

Thanks - Derrick

Comment: [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm under the impression TargetNullValue can't be set to a binding?

Comment: Ah crap, speed reading through SO questions inattentively is a bad habit I need to break. However you're correct, you'll need to throw a converter at it instead, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565213/how-to-bind-a-localized-string-in-the-targetnullvalue-attribute) looks on track. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `BindingPriority` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the MSDN link with some more info about the subject. HTH

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks for the additional feedback, I do believe the Converter would have worked, but I found myself preferring to use the BindingPriority suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to XAMIMAX's comment I was able to find a solution using PriorityBinding.

XAML

```
<Page x:Class="GenericProject.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GenericProject"
      xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:GenericProject.View">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter x:Key="NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--Additional markup-->
        <vw:GenericView>
            <vw:GenericView.DataContext>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Generic" Converter="{StaticResource NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter}" />
                    <Binding Path="GenericFactory" />
                </PriorityBinding>
            </vw:GenericView.DataContext>
        </vw:GenericView>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Converter

```
public class NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ?? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your factory works so this is probably not working code but you should be handling this logic in the view model, your view should just set the datacontext.

```
public GenericViewModel Generic
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(_generic == null)
            {
                GenericFactory.Create();
            }
            return _generic;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (_generic != value)
            {
                _generic = value;
                base.OnPropertyChanged("Generic");
            }
        }
    }
```

This will return null for Generic but when `OnGenericFactoryCreatedGeneric` is called it will set Generic and then cause the binding to update to a newly created view model.

If your factory has a synchronous create that returns the ViewModel then that would be better as Generic will never return null. `_generic = GenericFactory.Create();`

Comment: This would work for a simpler implementation of the GenericFactory, in my case the GenericFactory is a ViewModel in and of itself that contains a Command and requires a CommandParameter provided by the view to build the GenericViewModel.